# Advertising on PyQt5

Tags: pyqt5, ads

I have been searching and I cannot find any way to add advertisements on a PyQt5 application. Is this just not possible? If it is not, is there a way to embed HTML in the application to use Google Adwords or something along those lines?

Comment: Have a look at [QWebEngineView](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwebengineview.html).

Comment: Thank you, this looks exactly what I am looking for!

Answer (score 0):

What I did was to use PyQt5-WebEngine to call in the Ads, I created a responsive page and linked that to the PyQt5 Application